# How to work out the month end date from the month - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a column that returns integers for months i.e. 7 for July. What I want to do is take this 7 and return the month end i.e. 31-july-2012, is there a function that allows me to do this in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked Google?  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) has a page of date and time functions.  There doesn't seem to be a built in 'last day of month' function.  But the calculation is the day before the first day of the next month.

Comment: Have you considered just adding another table as a lookup?  Since there's a small, known number of months, this would be pretty easy to do...

Comment: Yeah I had a look via Google but couldnt get my head around the end of the month from just the month number

Comment: If you looked via Google and weren't sure how to interpret what you found, then say so; it helps give you credibility, and helps people know how to explain to you.  See [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) for a pointed view on the issue of how to ask questions, but explaining what you've looked at and don't understand is a good idea.

Comment: _Why_ do you want the **end** of the month?  Please be aware that it's usually better to use 'exclusive' upper bounds, than 'inclusive' ones, especially if the datatype may change date -> timestamp (and especially given the number of those types SQL Server has...).  If it's so you can use this in a `BETWEEN` function (ie, `datCol BETWEEN @start AND @end`), you'd be better off using the exclusive range (ie `datCol >= @start AND datCol < @start + 1 MONTH`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
DECLARE @Month int
DECLARE @Year int

set @Month = 7
set @Year = datepart(year,getdate())

select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)))
```

Results:

```
2012-07-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this;

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

this is the bit you're interested in;

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```